# How I can convert XML to JSON? without special libraries. >JAVA

Tags: java, xml, json

I have a big doubt. 
How I can save the data of an XML file to a list or array in JAVA?

It's a school project, I can not use special libraries like JDOM or JParser etc.

If only you could help me with the idea on saving would appreciate it very much. I was using indexOf and lastIndexOf.

Also how I can convert XML files to JSON or JSON to XML? No special libraries.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you're not willing to use a library for this, you've got a great deal of work to do, more than can reasonably be covered in  an answer here.

Comment: I know, I searched for examples and always with libraries. 
The teacher said no libraries and tried a lot and achievement only remove "<>" in the first line.

Comment: Yeah, well, looks like you've got a few nights waiting for you in the computer lab. Good luck.

Comment: A general XML parser is a gigantic project. I doubt if you teacher can even do it. It certainly doesn't fit in a school project. But is the project only about a special XML structure?

Comment: Sounds like you need to show your teacher that you are able to work with input streams and file readers.

Comment: For the purpose of the project is open, modify and save an XML or JSON file. 
The data are handled in an XML or JSON save in an array or a list. 
Then convert the XML to JSON and vice versa. 
If I can upload files (with libraries), which is not let me use special libraries XML or JSON. Or to convert or anything, everything is manual. 

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done in 2 stages:

1st - How to parse an XML file.
Consider an `XML` a `tree` data structure - You'll need to build that tree.
Each node in an XML contains a hash of attributes, and an array of child nodes - So would your "node" object.
Work recursively and parse the XML text into this tree. 
parseNode (xmlText):

- If node has attributes - parse them
- If node has children: For each (parseNode(Its own text tag part)) and add to node object

2nd - would be writing to JSON, also recursively writeJSON (node):

- If node has attributes, write them
- If node has children, begin array, and for each chile, writeJSON (child)

It's a lot of work, but not too hard once you understand the process

Comment: Thanks, Someone also told me the same thing, really hard for me because I've never seen trees. 
Today I was trying with another form (I removed the <>) with two functions: 

public static String read (String line) {

int start = linea.indexOf ("<"); 
int end = linea.indexOf (">"); 
Linea.substring String str = (start +1, end); 
return string; 
}

Comment: can anyone have code for convertion of xml to json without using libraries, send to me navinas33@gmail.com